# pass data from child input element to parent in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, data-binding, vue-component, vue-reactivity

I want to transmit the data from the input element of the child comp to the parent comp data property

using the`$emit` method the data can be transmited to the parent

directly binding the transmited property  on the child property
using `v-bind`     `<input   v-model="userinput" />`
results in a Warning

```
runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:6870 [Vue warn]: Extraneous non-emits event listeners (transmitData) were passed to component but could not be automatically inherited because component renders fragment or text root nodes. If the listener is intended to be a component custom event listener only, declare it using the "emits" option. 
  at <UserInput onTransmitData=fn<bound receaveData> > 
  at <App>
```

what is the correct way to do this kind of operation ?

```
\\ child

<template>


     
     <input   v-model="userinput" /> 

    <button type="button" @click="transmitData">transmit</button>

</template>

<script>
export default {
 
        

data() {
    return {
        userinput: " dd",
      
    }
},

methods: {
    transmitData(event){
        this.$emit('transmit-data', this.userinput)
    }

}



}
</script>
```

```
\\ parent

<template>
 
  <user-input @transmit-data="receaveData" />



  <p>{{ childData }}</p>
</template>

<script>
import UserInput from "./components/UserInput.vue";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    UserInput,
  },

  data() {
    return {
    
      childData: " "
    };
  },

  methods: {

    receaveData(compTransmit){
      console.log(compTransmit)
      this.childData = compTransmit

    },

    
   
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to specify a emits **option** in the child component
[docs](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/emits-option.html)

so in your case should look like this

```js
export default {
emits: ['transmit-data'], // you need to add this :)
data() {
    return { userinput: " dd" }
},
methods: {
    transmitData(event){
        this.$emit('transmit-data', this.userinput)
    }
}
}
```